# I complie test code of svgpp ,there is error forbids declaration of ‘BOOST_DELETED_FUNCTION’ with no type。But I have install boost

Tags: svg, boost

I compile some test code of svgpp ,there is error: `forbids declaration of ‘BOOST_DELETED_FUNCTION’ with no type`

I have installed boost, the error is like this:

> /home/jiantang/download/svgpp-master/src/test/../../include/svgpp/policy/error.hpp:136:99:
>   error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘BOOST_DELETED_FUNCTION’ with no
>   type [-fpermissive]
>   BOOST_DELETED_FUNCTION(unknown_css_property_error& operator=
>   (unknown_css_property_error const&))

when I compile by command: `g++ full_parse_main.cpp -lboost_system.`
It is still causing this error

> /usr/include/svgpp/detail/adapt_context.hpp:46:109: error: expected
>   ‘;’ at end of member declaration
>   BOOST_DELETED_FUNCTION(bind_context_parameters_wrapper& operator=
>   (bind_context_parameters_wrapper const&))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I have resolve the problem by update boost to 1.68.
My  boost is 1.54 before

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing `#include <boost/config.hpp>` in svgpp headers.

Comment: This cpp file is example of svgpp provided。And，I add “#include <boost/config.hpp>”，the problem still.